# Error: Installing PyObjus kivy

Tags: macos, kivy

I'm installing PyObjus:  *sudo python setup.py install*-> logging command:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pyobjus
copying pyobjus/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pyobjus
copying pyobjus/debug.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pyobjus
copying pyobjus/dylib_manager.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pyobjus
copying pyobjus/objc_py_types.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pyobjus
copying pyobjus/protocols.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pyobjus
copying pyobjus/test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pyobjus
running build_ext
cythoning pyobjus/pyobjus.pyx to pyobjus/pyobjus.c
building 'pyobjus' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pyobjus
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c pyobjus/pyobjus.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/pyobjus/pyobjus.o
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm using Xcode 5.1 on Mac 10.9. You can visit: https://github.com/kivy/pyobjus